# Drupal yml install files

Tags: drupal-8

I have several config items for my module, adding a field to the user entity and also adding a role.  Both configs are added in the \MY_MODULE\config\install and the install works great YAY!!!!!

Now when I uninstall the module the fields and the user role are still enabled in the system.  This makes no sense to me.

Does anyone know why or what I need to do to get it to uninstall without writing code in hook_uninstall (That is what I ended up doing for the fields but still does not make sense to me).

Content of the \MY_MODULE\config\install\user.role.tiimeoffadmin.yml

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: timeoffadministrator
label: 'Time Off Administrator'
weight: 1
is_admin: false
permissions:
- 'access comments'
- 'access content'
- 'add time off entities'
- 'edit time off entities'
- 'view published time off entities'
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ran across the item that fixed this issue.  For yml files there is the dependency section that needs added.  So adding the below fixed my issues with the fields and the role.

```
dependencies:
  module:
  - timeoff
  enforced:
    module:
    - timeoff
```

I credit this thread for the answer (Two people post that solution in there @Robert Ben Parkinson & @Ahmad)

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164612/how-do-i-remove-a-configuration-object-from-the-active-configuration